# Accessing Properties after jQuery keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a object called player

```
function Player(_x, _y, _speed) {
    this.x = _x;

    this.getX = function() {
        return this.x;
    };

    this.handleKeyDown = function(event) {
        console.log(this.x); // undefined
    };

    $(document.body).keydown(this.handleKeyDown);
}
```

Why doesn't "handleKeyDown" not see my x Property? And how do I work around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `this` doesn't work the way you think it does in javascript.  `this` is the context in which the current function is being executed.  So when you do something like... `object.doThing()`, then while executing `doThing()` this is pointing to object.  However you could call doThing() without the object reference, then `this` is the global object.

Below is the code you gave rewritten to use the concept of closures to avoid the `this` schenanigans.  This code can be further refactored to use prototypes and avoid the extra memory overhead of creating all the same functions over and over again but I don't want to junk this up with more information than is needed.

```
function Player(_x, _y, _speed) {
    var x = _x;

    var getX = function() {
        return x;
    };

    var handleKeyDown = function(event) {
        console.log(x);
    };

    $(document.body).keydown(handleKeyDown);
}
```

An eye-opening method in Javascript that shows that `this` does not operate the way you initially thought would be the [MDN docs for Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Comment: In that case you use `this`.

Comment: You said _"This code can be further refactored to use prototypes"_, referring to your code with lexically scoped variables.  Your advice was contradictory.

Comment: Where was it implied that it would stay as written in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Because the `this` in your keydown handler is the element itself (in this case, `document.body`). You need to either

```
var self = this;
$(document.body).keydown(function() { self.handleKeyDown() });
```

Or look at using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

Answer (score 0):

If using ES5, you can use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (or on older browsers, shim it, or use `$.proxy`) to ensure that `this` is correctly set:

```
this.handleKeyDown = function(event) {
    console.log(this.x);
}.bind(this);
```

or you can maintain an external reference to `this` in your lexical scope:

```
var self = this;
this.handleKeyDown = function(event) {
    console.log(self.x);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

the `this` is 'document.body' here, not the object `Player`

Answer (score -1):

Because `this` represents the getX function, try this :

```
function Player(_x, _y, _speed) {
    var self = this;
    self.x = _x;

    self.getX = function() {
        return self.x;
    };

    self.handleKeyDown = function(event) {
        console.log(self.x);
    };

    $(document.body).keydown(self.handleKeyDown);
}
```

Edit : meh, I read to fast, I meant handleKeyDown. Anyway, the thing is that the context of `this` changes, so it is a good practice to store it in a `self` field to clarify your code and make sure you are refering to what you think.